# Django 1 parent table that contains 2 children models, instead of creating 2 children tables

Tags: django, database, orm

I have three models as following:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="%(class)ss")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Income(Transaction):
    INCOME_CATEGORIES = [
        ("YEARLY", "Yearly"),
        ("MONTHLY", "Monthly"),
        ("ONETIME", "One-time"),
    ]

    category = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=INCOME_CATEGORIES, null=False)

class Expense(Transaction):
    EXPENSE_CATEGORIES = [
        ("LUXURY", "Luxury"),
        ("ESSENTIAL", "Essential"),
    ]

    category = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=EXPENSE_CATEGORIES, null=False)
    can_be_cheaper = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

But this creates 2 tables for Income and Expense models. I want to have 1 table called Transaction that'll contain these child models in it, is this possible?

Comment: Look into https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Comment: @iklinac Proxy models don't allow me to add fields though, as far as I understand, right?